# What is purpose of items in function parentheses?

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

```
function handleButtonClick(e) {
var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
var songName = textInput.value;
//alert("Adding " + songName);

if (songName == "") {
    alert("Please enter a song");
}
else {
    //alert("Adding " + songName);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = songName;
    var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
    ul.appendChild(li);

    // for Ready Bake
    save(songName);
}
}
```

At this code why we put an "e" into function that stays in first line. As far as i can see, we didn't used it except there?

Comment: `e` is an Euler's number approximately equals to `2.7182818284`. It is widely used in logarithms and calculus. Your computer doesn't know this constant which is why it is crucial to include it in all event handlers.

Comment: @Lion I don't think that this comment is very helpful. Presumably you are trying to be funnny, but you forgot to add one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley

Comment: @Pumbaa80:) I could have added that smiley symbol, if the comment box had allowed to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the name of the function, I'm assuming this is a click handler attached to a button on your page. Normally, when an event is triggered, the browser passes an Event object as an argument to the event handler. In your code, the e argument would contain this Event object. In your event handler you are not using the passed in Event object and hence this can be removed.

However, at times you may want to use the passed in event object. For example: you may want a certain action to be performed when the button is clicked and a different action to be performed when the button is clicked with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key held down. In this case, you would use the ctrlKey property of the passed in Event object to determine which action to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use it now but :

- this parameter, an event, is received even if you don't declare it, if you provide it as callback to an event binding utility (for example `myElement.onclick=handleButtonClick;`)
- it's possible that your event handler will have to use the event in the future, it's cleaner to declare it now

You don't *have* to declare it, but it's a good practice.